# Just Installed OpenSUSE, and the Fonts for Firefox and Eclipse are HUGE, what Can I Do?

Tags: firefox, fonts, eclipse, opensuse

I just installed openSUSE 11.3 (I think) using VMWare 7.1. My question is that when I run certain apps (Firefox and Eclipse are good examples), the font sizes are all scaled super huge. It isn't that the default sizes are 18-24 point, they aren't. It is that the 10 point font looks like it is 18 point or more.

The menus and dialogs all have huge fonts - I am assuming that it is that they are scaled up. I don't know.

This seems like it would be a common problem since all I did was take the default install and install eclipse.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly OpenSuse uses a default font resolution of 106, you can change this by right click the desktop - Change Background - fonts tab then click details. Try lowering it to 96 or so.

[image]